# Seeing GET /server-status every 10 seconds from localhost in access log

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, access-log

I'm using nginx for a reverse proxy in a lab environment for a POC.  While looking through the nginx access.log file I see this entry every 10 seconds

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2019:02:16:50 +0000] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

I'm trying to figure out what is the source of this and reason behind it.  It's really just curiosity and me trying to understand more about nginx as a reverse proxy.  Where else should I be looking to further understand what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm about a year late to answering, but for me this was a request made by [Netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/) and disabling its NGINX statistics collector removed these requests.